# image is not visible in Created Multi-Sheet Excel Workbook from Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, excel

I want to add an image in  Multi-Sheet Excel Workbook.I have successfully created a excel file with data but image is still not visible in excel.

I have attache my code snippet here.Please help me with this.

[image: code screen shot]

Comment: post the code you used for creating the excel file, otherwise there is almost impossible for us to spot the issue

Comment: I have added a VF page code